# Using UADetector To detect Robots

Tags: java, user-agent, bots

I am testing Java user-agent detector API http://uadetector.sourceforge.net. According to the project home page the API can detect robots. But looking at the docs and playing around with the API I can't find reference to Robots.

Can anyone direct me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getOnlineUpdatingParser();
ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
UserAgentType type = agent.getUserAgentType();  // this can be ROBOT, BROWSER, etc.
```

For more information, check [this site](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/modules/uadetector-core/apidocs/net/sf/uadetector/UserAgentType.html) and [this example](https://github.com/before/uadetector/tree/master/examples/helloworld).

Comment: @ErikPragt i am using your code in scala but getting error `not found: value UADetectorServiceFactory`

Comment: @ErikPragt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776617/not-found-value-uadetectorservicefactory