# not found: value UADetectorServiceFactory

Tags: scala, browser, user-agent, bots

On the reference of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790577/using-uadetector-to-detect-robots), I try the below code in Scala:

```
import net.sf.uadetector._
def check = Action { implicit request =>
    println(request.headers)
    var parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getOnlineUpdatingParser();
    println(parser)
    val agent = parser.parse(request.headers.get("User-Agent").getOrElse(""))
    println(agent)
    val which = agent.getUserAgentType(); // this can be ROBOT, BROWSER, etc.
    println(which)
    Ok(write(Map("result" -> true)))
}
```

and

> libraryDependencies += "net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-core" %
>   "0.9.16"

but I am getting an error:

```
not found: value UADetectorServiceFactory

var parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getOnlineUpdatingParser();

             ^
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

> did i am missing something?

Yes, you have imported everything from `net.sf.uadetector` package, but [UADetectorServiceFactory](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/modules/uadetector-resources/apidocs/net/sf/uadetector/service/UADetectorServiceFactory.html) resides in `net.sf.uadetector.service`

Add

```
import net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory
```

or

```
import net.sf.uadetector.service._
```

And compilation should be okay

Comment: i am getting error `object service is not a member of package net.sf.uadetector`

Answer (score 0):

> did i am missing something?

Yes, I got what I am missing, but `getUserAgentType` is not still working so I used `getType()` in place of that.

```
import net.sf.uadetector.service._
import net.sf.uadetector._

def check = Action { implicit request =>
  var parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getOnlineUpdatingParser()
  println(parser)
  val agent = parser.parse(request.headers.get("User-Agent").getOrElse(""))
  println(agent)
  val which = agent.getType()
  println(which)
  Ok(write(Map("result" -> true)))
}
```

and needed two library dependencies to run the code above:

- "net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-core" % "0.9.16",
- "net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-resources" % "2013.04",

Comment: poor form not to accept om-nom-nom's answer of your original question.